# Error importing template source loader pyjade.ext.django.Loader

Tags: python, django, pyjade

Jade is a great template.I wanna use it in Django and I found Pyjade.

I follow the example code but I got error when I run the project.

In Django Debug Mode , Django told me :

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
Error importing template source loader pyjade.ext.django.Loader: "cannot import name force_text"
```

When I try to use

```
pyjade index.jade
```

I can get the correct result but with 3 warning:

```
WARNING:root:cannot import name force_text
WARNING:root:No module named jinja2.ext
WARNING:root:No module named tornado.template
```

Here is my setting.py

```
...

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('pyjade.ext.django.Loader',(
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
)

...
```

I use pip to install pyjade on my Django==1.4

Does anybody meet this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Where is your django installed in?I think you run django at 1.1 or lower version indeed, take a look at the discuss https://groups.google.com/d/topic/django-users/CEvCz-IwLQc/discussion

Comment: nope ... I am using Django==1.4.:-(

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link and u would solve the problem.Maybe u can install the lastest version of pyjade to solve this problem.

The author helped me and close this issue : https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade/issues/85

Have fun.